# The sum of the an SQL query and its opposite doesn't match the total count

Tags: sql, sqlite

The sum of the following 2 queries yields me 42 081 :

Query 1 :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SIREN) AS new_column FROM CDEdelux
WHERE Email IS NOT NULL
AND Email <> ""
AND Email <> " "
AND Email <> ''
AND Email <> ' '
AND Email LIKE "%@%.%"
AND Email NOT LIKE "_@%.%"
AND Email NOT LIKE "%bpi%"
AND Email NOT LIKE "%BPI%"
AND Email NOT LIKE "%inconnu%"
AND Email NOT LIKE "%tempo%"
AND Email NOT LIKE "%attente%"
AND Email NOT LIKE "%xx%"
AND Email NOT LIKE "%nsp%"
AND Email NOT LIKE "%contact%"
AND Email NOT LIKE "%info%"
AND Email NOT LIKE "%recuperer%"
```

Query 2 (opposite query) :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SIREN) AS new_column FROM CDEdelux
WHERE Email IS NOT NULL
AND Email <> ""
AND Email <> " "
AND Email <> ''
AND Email <> ' '
AND (Email NOT LIKE "%@%.%"
OR Email LIKE "_@%.%"
OR Email LIKE "%bpi%"
OR Email LIKE "%BPI%"
OR Email LIKE "%inconnu%"
OR Email LIKE "%tempo%"
OR Email LIKE "%attente%"
OR Email LIKE "%xx%"
OR Email LIKE "%nsp%"
OR Email LIKE "%contact%"
OR Email LIKE "%info%"
OR Email LIKE "%recuperer%")
```

However since they're supposed to be opposite and complementary, they should give me 39 206, which is the result of that query :

Query 3 (total query) :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SIREN) AS new_column FROM CDEdelux
WHERE Email IS NOT NULL
AND Email <> ""
AND Email <> " "
AND Email <> ''
AND Email <> ' '
```

Why is the first number higher than the second ?

Comment: Can a *SIREN* have more than one *Email*?

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously a given `SIREN` could have multiple emails that match either set of conditions.  You can see the duplicate emails by doing:

```
select distinct siren, email
from CDEdelux d1
where exists (select 1 from CDEdelux d2 where d2.siren = d.siren and d2.email <> d.email);
```

If you counted distinct `email`s, then the numbers should add up.